# cannot connect to samba shares

Tags: samba

I'm on ubuntu server and out of the blue when I try to connect to samba shares it tells me it cannot find the shares but it can see the folder.

I'm connecting via ViMu on a googletv box.

I've not changed any configs since last using it.

Answer (score 0):

Samba troubles could be a number of things, i'm just going to list a few things you could try:

Rule out the firewall. Disconnect the Internet then disable the firewalls and see if it works, if you hook up something you now have something to work on.

make sure your "smb.conf" file has a mention of: "name resolve order" with your prefered settings.

If the target machine is windows based, validate the network settings. Mainly file sharing, network discovery and user protected access. Also all needed server, local machine, etc... services.

Assuming you're running on a user based network, make sure the passwords are defined.

Random problems sometimes randomly go away, when all else fails try rebooting.

Make sure both machines are on the same workgroup? Maybe? Probably not because you say it worked before.

Double check ownership and security permissions for the shared folders.

That is about all i could think of. I would suggest running through the list, ruling out every problems. Then if the problem persists and you have an error message, toss it in google and read up about others having the same problem.

Trying to help. o/